# WPF GridViewColumn Value Converter Error

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

Can anybody tell me what is the difference between these two approaches to make your GridViewColumn appear as image according to the dbfield value.

First

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ActionId, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource local:ActionIdConverter}}" />
```

Second

```
<Image>
        <Image.Source>
                <Binding Path="ActionId" Mode="OneWay">
                        <Binding.Converter>
                                <local:ActionIdConverter />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                </Binding>
        </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Second is working fine but First is giving

> Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder'
>   threw an exception.
>   **Inner Exception Message is** Cannot find resource named
>   'local:ActionIdConverter'. Resource
>   names are case sensitive.

but same Converter is working in Second

any idea what i am missing in my First approach?

Thanks and Regards,
Adnan

Comment: It looks like you've never used resources before, you might want to read up on it: [Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach creates a new instance of `ActionIdConverter`, whereas the first is looking for it in the resources.

To fix the first code snippet, add the converter to a parent element `Resources` section, then reference it using the key you gave it eg:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:ActionIdConverter x:Key="ActionIdConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ActionId, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ActionIdConverter}}" />
```

That way, you can reuse the same converter instance in multiple places rather than create a new one each time.